# Replacing switched 14/2 with 14/3

Tags: electrical

I have a 14/2 wire going from a switch to an outlet such that both plugs in the outlet are switched.

I'm going to replace the 14/2 with 14/3 so that one plug gets constant power while the other is switched.

**My questions are:**

- If the 14/2 is nailed to the stud inside the wall what do I do with the old cable?
- Do I wire nut it inside both boxes?
- Can I just cut the ends off and push into the wall side there will be no power on the cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leave it in the boxes, capped, or chop it off. The problem with leaving it in the boxes is you may run up against box fill rules. If you do leave wires in the boxes, even temporarily, any wire by itself should generally have a piece of tape over the wire nut and wire insulation to make sure the cap stays on as the caps generally are designed to hold properly with 2 or more wires.

Comment: Can I chop the end and push it out of the box into the wall? That way I don't exceed the box limit

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "chop it off". Then it is just a random disconnected wire floating in the wall for someone to wonder "What?" 20 years from now.